# PHP mysql video uploading form check

Tags: php, file, if-statement, upload

Hi i'm trying to make a video uploading site, where people can upload, and they can, but they can upload without choosing a file?
And i don't want them to be able to upload without choosing a file to upload.

This is my code :)

```
<?php

mysql_connect("IP","Username","password");
mysql_select_db("DB");

if(isset($_POST['submit']) && !empty($_FILES['file']))
{

    $nann = $_POST['nann']; 
    $name = $_FILES['file']['name'];
    $temp = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
    $desc = $_POST['desc'];
    $log_username1 = $_POST['log_username'];

    move_uploaded_file($temp,"uploaded/".$name);
    $url = "http://www.dkminedanish.dk/videoer/uploaded/$name";
    mysql_query("INSERT INTO `db` VALUE ('','$name','$url','$desc','$log_username1','$nann')");
}else
{
echo "Du har ikke valgt nogen fil!";
}

?>
```

Comment: What is the problem? I think you didnt descript about the problem in your question.

Comment: Daniel, you may want to do two checks: one in the client side (check, for example, if the value of the file input has something in it) and other in the server side (not only if $_FILES is empty but if the desired index has valid data on it and has been uploaded correctly). Check http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.php "error messages explained" and "common pitfalls".

Answer (score 1):

Request variables, like `$_POST` or `$_FILES` can easily be manipulated by the client.
They can pretty much send any data they want in those variables via for example the console in the webrowser.

This enables stuff like Sql-Injections, whish is when malicious sql querys are sent with the params and then executed cause the developer have not escaped all the data correctly.
Always escape anything passed from the client that are queried to the database.

You are using the old deprecated mysql_* api, this will be removed in future php releases and should therefore not be used if possible. I would recommend taking a look at the mysqli or pdo api and migrate to one of those.
Both mysqli and pdo have *prepared statements*, those are very useful when it comes to sql-injection defense, cause they escape the data for you!

When it comes to your initial question. You are only checking if the `$_FILES` variable is not empty, not whats in it!
Try check `if(isset($_FILES['file']))` also.

Comment: The sql injection part of my answer is kinda important, cause you are supplying us with both a url and a sql query that is possible to inject to.

Answer (score 1):

If I am not wrong, did you mean without uploading any thing data still goes to MySQL Database.

So change your `if` condition like this.

```
if(isset($_POST['submit']) && !empty($_FILES['file']['name']))
```

OR use [is_upload_file](http://php.net/is_uploaded_file)

```
if(isset($_POST['submit']) && is_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name']))
```

As `$_FILES` always holding some data for example size `0`.

Comment: ^^ if i do that i can't go to my site

Comment: Can't go to my site means  ?

Comment: If i type my website url in the search bar then it's just white screen

Comment: And what error you see there  ? I suggest turn on Errors in development `error_reporting(E_ALL|E_STRICT);` and let us know what is the error

Comment: If this slove your problem, cosider to accept the answer